# How to change , into . in a list?

Tags: r, list, numbers, recode

I read certain files into R as list. The data contains `,` instead of `.` between numbers.
Data at the end is what I can import into R directly, but it includes commas.

```
library(dplyr)

mat1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("2,1", "3,2", "4,5"),
                 x2 = c("4,5", "8,9", "2,7"))

mat2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("1,2", "3,33", "5,55"),
                 x2 = c("8,3", "4,5", "1,9"))

mat3 <- data.frame(x1 = c("3,44", "2,2", "8,88"), 
                   c("9,5", "4,7", "6,4"))

data <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)
```

Comment: When reading in the files using `read.table` use the `dec = ","` argument.

Comment: Ahhh perfect thank you. I thought I have to write dec = ".", so what I want to have in the end, not what is already there and I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `format(number, decimal.mark = '.')` or for the other way round `format(number, decimal.mark = ',')`.

(I'm new here and this is one of my first contributions, so please don't be mad at me if it's not perfect. If I write any nonsence, I am happy about a comment to correct me.)

Comment: sorry it's not working. I am beginner as well so no worries.